# STS mapping controller to view

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am studying STS

I am started starter project with jpa,web

my code SpringProjectApplication.java is

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringProjectApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringProjectApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

and my Homecontroller.java is

```
package com.example;


import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@RestController
public class HomeController {


/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping("/")
public String helloWorld(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "home";
}



@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String verifyLogin(Locale locale, Model model) {

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/SignUp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String SignUp(Locale locale, Model model) {

    return "SignUp";
}
}
```

and servlet-context.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="come.example" />
```

and home.jsp is

[image]

overall structure is

[image]

I think if homecontroller is mapped with home.jsp

localhost:8080/ show "hello world"

but result is "home"

so not mapped

I want to solve it.

***help me.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render a view -> meaning you want to show home.jsp page you need to change your class annotation from @RestController to @Controller. With 
@RestController u return JSON or XML, also uncomment internalViewResolver Bean in your servlet-context.xml.

Comment: by @RestController->@Controller, error message is changed. thank you